# Cakephp 3 - reusable code for Table Entities

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have some code, that I need to apply for multiple Tables' Entities

similar to the example here
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators

```
 protected function _setTitle($title)
 {
     // code to make re-usable 

     return $title;
 }
```

Where can I move my code, so I can access it from multiple Entities. I tried a function inside Behavior, but it did not work.

Thanks

Comment: @AD7six, I need to set a new field, but based on some conditions, which I read from `Configure::read`. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this one of two ways. First, using a trait (a bit like what you were trying to achieve with a behavior):-

```
class Example extends Entity
{
    use TitleTrait;
}

trait TitleTrait 
{

    protected function _setTitle($title)
    {
        return $title;
    }

}
```

Second way is by using inheritance:-

```
class Example extends CustomEntity
{

}

abstract class CustomEntity extends Entity
{

    protected function _setTitle($title)
    {
        return $title;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where should I put the trait code from the first way ?

Comment: @dav it's up to you (I think). I personally create a `src/Traits` directory and place them in there.